# Sonar exclusions/inclusions

Tags: java, maven, sonarqube, code-coverage

I'm trying to improve the coverage reports for my project and I want to exclude some packages **BUT INCLUDING** subpackages. For instance, I have this structure

```
src/main/java/com/myapp
    └ model
        └ mapper
            └ SomeMapperClass.java
        └ SomeModelClass.java --> exclude this and others...
        └ ...
        └ ClassToInclude.java --> but include this
    └ service
```

and I want to exclude `model` package but include `mapper` and `ClassToInclude`. Is there any way to do this without having to add every excluded class one by one? I would want something like this in `pom.xml`:

```
<sonar.coverage.exclusions>
    **/model/**/*.java
</sonar.coverage.exclusions>
<sonar.coverage.inclusions>
    **/model/mapper/**/*.java
    **/model/ClassToInclude.java
<sonar.coverage.inclusions>
```

Any help, guide, options and/or workarounds is appreciated. Thanks in advance for your answers.

### UPDATE #1

I found a way to include the subpackages only using `sonar.coverage.exclusions` property by doing:

```
<sonar.coverage.exclusions>
    **/model/*.java
</sonar.coverage.exclusions>
```

With this you exclude every class in `model` but not in `model.mapper`. Now I just need a way to solve how to include specific class in an excluded package.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While you can *exclude* some files *from coverage*, you can only *include* files as a whole. That is, exclusion is granular, but inclusion is not (i.e. `sonar.coverage.inclusions` doesn't exist), so I don't think this will work the way you're currently trying to do it.

That said, this should be doable with only exclusions if you craft them carefully, i.e. `**/model/*.java` rather than `**/model/**/*.java`.

Comment: and what about `ClassToInclude`? Should I exclude the rest of the package class by class?

Comment: ... or reorganize your packaging.

Comment: That's not an option unfortunately, I'll take your answer. As a side note, it would be a great feature to add `sonar.coverage.inclusions` property in a future version, do you have any feature request site?